# Why do my shortcut icons get broken on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

I have a strange problem. My icons seem to disappear randomly on my Windows 7. They were there a while back, now they ain't.

It happens often and quite randomly. Anyone know a fix?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the path to the executable is still valid?

Comment: Yes, quite sure.

Comment: Yet another solution, easiest one yeT: http://www.sordum.org/9194/rebuild-shell-icon-cache-v1-1/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the answer:

1. Run "regedit"
2. Go to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
3. Change "***Max Cached Icons***" to 10000 or more. **Upper and Lowercase SENSITIVE!**
4. If it doesn't exist create it as new "string"
5. Reboot

After that

1. Go to
   "`C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local`"
2. Delete ***IconCache.db***
3. Reboot again

Or try this solution that always works for me:

```
open cmd-console in admin mode
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
DEL IconCache.db /a
start explorer.exe via taskmanager
```

Edit 2016-05-07: Easiest solution: [Link](http://www.sordum.org/9194/rebuild-shell-icon-cache-v1-1/)

Comment: @NoCanDO: YesWeCan!

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have found that if you try to delete the IconCache.db file while explorer.exe is running, the icon cache will not be rebuilt. You need to open a command prompt, kill explorer.exe with task manager, delete the icon cache file and then start explorer.exe with the task manager.

Comment: The link worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I found the cause of the misteriously disappearing Windows 7 desktop icons and the reason why Show desktop icons now and then gets unchecked.

It’s INFRARECORDER !! Try for yourselves, when you start Infrarecorder and close it again, go have a look at “Show desktop icons”, it is unchecked (but the icons are still there). Check it on again and start Infrarecorder…. it is unchecked again.

This Windows 7 “bug” is irritating me since the beginning and now I found the cause: It’s Infrarecorder which is causing this problem.

Test it, please let me know and spread the news :-)

Comment: **:From Anders:** I would never have figured it out since I very seldom use Infrarecorder:)

It seems people are aware at the forum:
http://infrarecorder.org/?p=114

Comment: **:From Rogier:** In My case it was infra recorder as well.

Very strange behaviour. (Also not too happy with the program itself, so its bye bye to IR)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the paths are still valid, try right clicking on the shortcuts and go to the "shortcut" tab. Click on the change icon button, and see if the icon you want is in the list (if there is any list at all).

I don't know why Windows is losing track of the icon (It's happened to me a few times), but hopefully this will provide a workaround.

Comment: I did. Doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that your C:\Windows\Installer folder is empty. In this folder Office or Windows Live software installs its icons and stuff...

When this is the case, you can try to copy the {...}-folders (with some kind of identity) to your own machine.

*Edit: Added a link to a forum-post: http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/49813-microsoft-office-2010-icons-missing.html*

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft Fix It** service solves this problem without any editing work. Get it from [here](http://www.askvg.com/microsoft-releases-fix-for-random-incorrect-icon-change-problem-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/). It worked well for me. This service finds the problems and troubleshoots them.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily bring all the icons on the desktop as described in the following:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3659-desktop-items-hide-show.html

Yes, it is tru, it is an InfraRecorder that makes them disappear.

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 7 Professional, and have been struggling with this frustrating problem for a while now.  I have tried the solution recommended here, and increasing the max cached icons seemed to fix it for a while, then the problem came back.

I finally mentioned it to my co-workers, and one of them said I should check my Windows PATH, and shorten it if it's very long.  It turns out the system PATH was over 2500 bytes in length!  I removed a lot of cruft and brought it down to about 1k in size, and voila!  The problem has not appeared since.