# Windows 7 File Explorer Icons not displaying properly

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer

[image]

So see how the icons are not right for some of my libraries. How can I fix this. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit on an HP Envy 14. Any ideas?

[image]

Even regular folders are missing their icons.

Comment: [Rebuild the icon cache](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/bea47202-d869-4155-8c8f-2a5b8bd7be1d/)

Comment: Didn't fix it but thanks. The biggest issue I'm having in finding a solution is that I don't know how to phrase my problem to get hits in Google. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the problem also on the Desktop?

Comment: This could solve your problem: 
http://superuser.com/questions/58092/why-do-my-shortcut-icons-get-broken-on-windows-7

Comment: @Chris no, just in file explorer

Comment: @Chris and thank you but still no fix. As you can see from the images, its mostly folders and other Windows icons

Comment: I should also mention that IconCache.db has yet to rebuild itself :S